# Losing data with GetOverlappedResult?

Tags: c++, winapi, io, serial-port

I have a thread that constantly looks for new data and if the data is not already in the serial buffer, `ReadFile` and `GetOverlappedResult` seem to tell me there's data, and that it read it, but not transfer it into my buffer...

```
func read()
{
    if(state == 0)
    {
        memset(bytes, '\0', sizeof(amount_to_read));

        readreturn = ReadFile(h, bytes, amount_to_read,NULL, osReader);
        if(readreturn <= 0)
        {
            errorcode = GetLastError();
            if(errorcode != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            {
                SetEAIError(ERROR_INTERNALERROR);
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (GetOverlappedResult(h, osReader, &dwRead, FALSE) == false)
    {
        errorcode = GetLastError();

        if (errorcode == ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE || errorcode == 0)
        {
            if(dwRead > 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            //timeout
            SetEAIError(ERROR_EAITIMEOUT);
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            //other error 
            SetEAIError(ERROR_WIN_ERROR);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //read succeded, check if we read the amount required
        if(dwRead != amount_to_read)
        {
            if(dwRead == 0)
            {
                //nothing read, treat as timeout
                SetEAIError(ERROR_EAINOREAD);
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                //memcpy_s(bytes, sizeof(bytes), readbuf, dwRead);
                SetEAIError(ERROR_PARTIALREAD);
                *_bytesRead = dwRead;
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(strlen((char*)bytes) == 0)
            {
                //nothing read, treat as timeout
                SetEAIError(ERROR_EAINOREAD);
                return -1;
            }
            //memcpy_s(bytes, sizeof(bytes), readbuf, dwRead);
            *_bytesRead = dwRead;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the error codes mean:

- ERROR_TIMEOUT - switches the state to 1 so that it does not read again, which calls `GetOverlappedResult` again
- INTERNALERROR,ERROR_EAINOREAD - it resets state to 0
- ERROR_PARTIALREAD - starts a new read with new amount of bytes to read

If I swtich GetOverlappedResult to blocking (pass TRUE) it works every time.
If I switch my thread to only read when I know there is data there it works every time.

But if there is not data there, when there is data there it seems to "lose" the data, it my read amount parameter `dwRead` shows the correct number of bytes read (can see it read with a port monitor) but the bytes are not stored in my char*.

I constantly get ERROR_EAINOREAD

What am I doing wrong?

I do not want to use flags, I want to just use `ReadFile` and `GetOverlappedResult`, I should be able to accomplish this with the code I have....... I assume

Comment: your `memset(bytes, '\0', sizeof(amount_to_read));` is wrong, unless you only want to clear the first `n` bytes of your buffer, where `n` is the sizeof whatever the variable **type** of `amount_to_read` is. It may likely be why you *think* there is data there, but there actually isn't

Comment: agreed, should not be size of bytes...
the reason I think there is data there though is because getoverlappedresults sets the dwRead DWORD to 6 and yet my array is all zeros

 (ALSO to point out I know I am using strlen to test this, my data has no zeros so it was a quick hack, strlen returns on first null character and would usually not work, but that is not my issue either I have verified in my watch window)

Comment: OK, last question, where is `state` updated in this context? I ask because you obviously need to to kick off the read, but `state` is not in this code except for eval. I can assume it is outside of this? Whether it is your intention or not, this *looks* like you're essentially trying to issue an overlapped async read-request, then spin-looping on GetOverlappedResult trying to read data from it. I normally use alterable-io, or better still, IOCP for this, but there must be a reason you're not doing so.

Comment: Well I will have to say the reason I am not using those is because I am not familiar with them... :( - and yes state is updated outside in the main loop based on the return packet (see the error code explanation at bottom)
So what you are saying sounds like what I am doing, doing one read, and waiting for it to either timeout or give me data, if it times out I read again, if its not timedout yet then I continue to call get overllapedresults, if it gives me data I expect it to be there (its not)

From serial coms I have done in the past this was always suffice, are you saying it is not?

Comment: ANOTHER THING:
oddly enough changing my com timeouts to smaller numbers makes this almost non issue... This doesnt seem like a fix, because changing timeouts certianly shouldnt make data become "lost", but perhaps help someone point me in the right direction?
(commented is old)
 
 commTimeout.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;//500;
 commTimeout.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier  = 10;//500;
 commTimeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant    = 50;//500;
 commTimeout.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant   = 50;//2;
 commTimeout.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;//3;
 SetCommTimeouts(p, &commTimeout);

Comment: No worries on not being familiar, everyone has to learn sometime. Spin-looping IO in Windows is generally a bad idea. Sometimes it is necessary, but they are usually rare. The documentation on [Synchronous and Asynchronous IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683(v=vs.85).aspx) methodologies is pretty decent. I'm assuming you're program is single-threaded by the looks of this, which makes async-io somewhat challenging (not impossible, but difficult none-the-less).

Comment: ty, not single threaded - each "device" up to about 16 of them has a thread, read/write serial i/o on same thread, so imperative not to block to make sure writing is always ready

Comment: Just checked out your document... that pretty much sums up exactly what I am doing... using overlapped, not blocking my thread, polling to read every 10ms, waiting for something to write...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was exactly what was stated the data was getting lost... the REASON it was getting lost is because the bytes parameter passed into the readfile is a local variable in the parents thread.  being local it gets re initialized each cycle so after I come into the read again, skip the readfile and go to the overlappedresults, I am now potentially working with a different area of memory

Comment: That is certainly going to cause problems. The each IO op needs (a) its own OVERLAPPED strict, and (b) memory that is around so long as the request is 'out there' I'm glad you got *something* out of that doc =P